# using jsoup how to extract the content of the two div "lieu" and "Expire le"

Tags: jsoup

I want to extract the content of two specific div in this link
"http://tanitjobs.com/display-job/89658/Responsable-Production-CALL-CENTER.html?searchId=1428594845.2138&page=1"

the content of **Lieu** and **Expire le**

Comment: Please do not suggest inspecting external link. Make a jsfiddle and tell us about your concrete problem.

Comment: ok.i will give my problem

i want to extract only " champ2" with jsoup from

<div class="abc">
champ1
</div>
<div class="abc">
champ2
</div>
<div class="abc">
champ3
</div>

Comment: Update you original question with the code, and a better description. Don't use comments for code.

Comment: Don't post examples in comment since (1) they should be part of your original question (2) code is hard to read in comment. So [[edit]] your question to add more info about your problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is code writing request without description of difficulty which stops OP from writing such code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String url = "http://tanitjobs.com/display-job/89658/Responsable-Production-CALL-CENTER.html?searchId=1428594845.2138&page=1";

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

String lieu = doc.select("div.displayField").last().text();
String expireLe = doc.select("div.displayFieldBlock > h3").last().parent().ownText();

System.out.println(lieu);
System.out.println(expireLe);
```

Output:

```
DJERBA
2015-05-04
```

Comment: @JonazCz thanks a lot..ur answer helped me this is waht i need

Comment: @FaycelGsouma, It would be nice to _accept_ my answer if it helped you, by clicking the checkmark next to it :-)